# 1990s anime with Spaceship shaped like a white dragon and has guardian manned robots?

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, robots, anime

I have been trying to figure out the name of an a 1990s anime. It had a spaceship with the last remaining members of an alien humanoid race and their Princess. Not quite sure about this part but I think the ship comes to Earth where it finds pilots who can pilot its giant guardian robots which also turns into spacecrafts.

I think the ship was mainly white in colour and almost shaped like a dragon. One of the  robot/spacecraft pilots from Earth has a romantic relation with the Princess. I forgot why they were travelling through space but in the end, they find the ships true capabilities where it transforms into a sort of guardian for the galaxy.

Comment: Escaflowne fits some of this description, with the white dragon mecha gardian. But its not space based.

Comment: thanks for the reply, its not escaflowne, thats the first viable option but it doesn't have a spaceship. I also clearly remember that the main ship was space bound and housed the other robots inside it.

Comment: Part of me wants to say Voltron. But I've only seen the newest incarnation of the series so I can't be certain.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds a bit like [Ninja Senshi Tobikage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ninja_Senshi_Tobikage) with the reference of someone from Earth falling in love with a Princess. It also contains robots manned by pilots, spaceships merging with robots to create...bigger robots, etc.

The following excerpt is from the wiki link:

> Joe Maya is a 16-year-old who lives on Mars with his father. His dream is to return to Earth. He has two friends Mike Coil and Jenny Ai (Reni Ai in the Japanese original). During an escape from Martian military police, Joe and Mike stumble upon a crashed spaceship, the Xenos 5 (the El Shank).
>
> Inside, they encounter three human-looking aliens: **Princess Romina, whom Joe instantly finds attractive**, her willowy attendant Jade (Shaf), and a young red-headed general named Icelander (Irbora). But before they can converse, a group of robots land and attack the spaceship. As the three aliens hide, Joe jumps into a machine, but it turns out to be a ninja robot named Black Lion.
>
> **The battle leads outside the ship where a mysterious ninja robot Cybertron (Tobikage) suddenly appears**. It wipes out several of the enemy robots before it merges with Joe's robot, which transforms into a mechanical lion that eradicates the remaining attackers.