# Which mecha anime of the 90s has robots being piloted by blood fusing and smaller robot being summoned by knife

Tags: story-identification, anime, mecha

Which 90s anime is it?

Where pilots had their blood circulate through the robots and the lead protagonist was in love with the princess and used to summon a smaller more capable robot with a knife.

This robot was able to fuse with other bigger robots

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/81689/76401 ? Or mixing that and Escaflowne?

Comment: Is there blood in that one? Not familiar with it.

Answer (score 3):

*[Escaflowne](https://escaflowne.fandom.com/wiki/Escaflowne)*?

> Like all Guymelefs, Escaflowne uses Energists as its power source. However, it requires the blood of the one who wishes to pilot it to be placed on the Energist first. It will only accept those that it deems worthy to pilot it, and requires its wielder to possess a truly kingly spirit, and traditionally has only been piloted by the crowned kings of Fanelia.

From [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Vision_of_Escaflowne):

> Gaea is an alternate dimension that was created from the combined wishes of the inhabitants of Atlantis when it started to sink into the ocean. On Gaea, Earth is known as the Mystic Moon. Gaea's size, mass, atmospheric composition, temperature belts, and even seasons are the same as Earth’s. The series focuses on Hitomi Kanzaki and her adventures after she is transported to the world of Gaea, a mysterious planet where she can see Earth and its moon in the sky. Hitomi's latent psychic powers are enhanced on Gaea and she quickly becomes embroiled in the conflicts between the Zaibach Empire led by Emperor Isaac Dornkirk and the several peaceful countries that surround it. The conflicts are brought about by the Zaibach Empire's quest to revive the legendary power from the ancient city of Atlantis. As the series progresses, many of the characters' pasts and motivations, as well as the history of Atlantis and the true nature of the planet Gaea, are revealed.

### Opening theme

Comment: I don't remember knives or Guymelefs fusing together (though I last watched Escaflowne a lot ot time ago).

Comment: @lfurini Truthfully, I've never watched it, but it's the anime that comes up when I searched for blood-based mecha.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by fectin in a comment, it might be *[Ninja Senshi Tobikage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ninja_Senshi_Tobikage)* as per [1990s anime with Spaceship shaped like a white dragon and has guardian manned robots?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/81689/76401). While I can't find any description of the pilot's blood being circulated through the robots, the plot is a better match than *Escaflowne*.

> Joe Maya is a 16-year-old who lives on Mars and dreams of returning to Earth. He has two friends: Mike Coil and Jenny Ai. When escaping from the Martian military police, Joe and Mike stumble upon a crashed spaceship, the Xenos 5, being attacked by huge robots. In his attempt to escape chasing robots, Joe gets into the spaceship where he encounters three human-looking aliens: the beautiful Princess Romina, her willowy attendant Jade, and a young General Icelander. A robot locates them and the three aliens hide, leaving Joe to fend for himself. Joe tries hiding in a pile of glowing metal, which turns out to be a ninja robot named Black Lion. The battle leads outside the ship where a mysterious ninja robot Cybertron suddenly appears when the Black Lion struggles. It wipes out several enemy robots before merging with Joe's robot, transforming into a mechanical lion that destroys the remaining attackers.

That's a male protagonist, who falls for an alien princess, and he can summon (or at least they show up around him) a smaller robot (only 12 feet tall) named Cybertron, who can merge with the three larger robots.

[image: Image of one of the box sets, I believe showing Cybertron, aka Tobikage]

### Opening Credits