# Old obscure mech anime about a girl and a robot that gets activated by her blood

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime, mecha

I don't remember a lot of details; I was young when I watched it. I remember that it was in a dark setting, like most 1980s/early 1990s anime (though it could have been a late 90s or early 2000s, because CGI and pacing differences weren't introduced until a little after that, and it was a fully-drawn anime).

There was a girl with short hair who finds a mech somehow (I can't remember) but it gets activated by her blood on accident and she stays inside it for most of the duration of the movie. The protagonist is a skinny male who managed to find the twin to her robot and they fight. I remember that the few times when she's out of the robot it still protects her, and she had a little bird that was also powered by her blood.

Please help. I'm going crazy trying to find it so I can watch it again! I know for sure it's not *Appleseed*. Different setting. I remember a lot more open earth rather than city.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/280636/which-mecha-anime-of-the-90s-has-robots-being-piloted-by-blood-fusing-and-smalle might be relevant.